# MouseOver of Username to expand Rep/Info should be a Click event

Tags: discussion

The new Rep/Info summary that is expanded when mousing over your username is quit nifty. However, every time my mouse inadvertently moves over my username, the rep/info box expands which quickly becomes an annoyance. Hopefully I'm not alone in this campaign for a click *event.

**Edit** 
Alpine has a good idea in the comments, re: Use the down arrow for the mouseover event. And leave the username as a click event to the profile.

Answer (score 9):

It was a frequent complaint (among others) yesterday that it now took two clicks to get to your profile, so the popover was made mouseover and the profile was made direct click. So I'm afraid this is unlikely to garner much support.

Comment: How about adding the link to the popover on the down arrow and the link to the profile on the User Name.